# Feeding state from one parachain to another

Tags: storage, cumulus

I am interested in developing a pallet into which data from another parachain can be fed. For instance, consider two parachains: Para A and Para B. Para B implements the collectives pallet, and for the purpose of this example, let's assume that the members of this collective are fixed and do not change.

Let's say I want to add a pallet on Para A that would need to know the members of the collective from Para A. Would it be a feasible solution to create an extrinsic that would allow anyone to 'feed' this data into the pallet by providing a merkle proof such that Para A is able to verify the validity of the information by comparing it against Para B's state root which is read from the relay chain(via [RelayChainInterface](https://github.com/paritytech/cumulus/blob/d4bb2215bb28ee05159c4c7df1b3435177b5bf4e/client/relay-chain-interface/src/lib.rs#L100))?

Does this approach make sense, and has anyone already implemented something similar?

Edit: From my understanding parts of the relay chain state are inserted into the para via an inherent: [link](https://github.com/paritytech/cumulus/blob/d4bb2215bb28ee05159c4c7df1b3435177b5bf4e/primitives/parachain-inherent/src/lib.rs#L64). However this doesn't contain the head data from parachains. Would this need to be modified such that it includes the head data for other specific parachain(in the above example Para B) from where I want to feed the state?

Is it possible to conveniently specify which keys from the relay chain state should be included through the parachain inherent without modifying the `parachain-inherent` module?

Comment: Would be nice to have, yes. Dont know if its maybe possible as impromptu pallet, but the previous idea was to allow parachains to read each others' full states: https://github.com/paritytech/polkadot-sdk/issues/1960

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[ISMP](https://github.com/polytope-labs/ismp-substrate) is doing basically what you are asking for. Internally they collect the recent `relay_chain_storage_root`s. Based on these `storage_root`s you can write your custom logic that sends a relay chain proof over the `ParaHead` and then a proof from the parachain itself.

> Is it possible to conveniently specify which keys from the relay chain state should be included through the parachain inherent without modifying the parachain-inherent module?

Currently not, but feel free to open a pull request for this. It is also somewhere on my TODO list ;)